# Batch add image

Tags: python

[image]

I have made a book turning animation. There is a file containing hundreds of image sequences, but it is difficult to add images to hundreds of planes. How can I use python to make a plug-in?

Comment: Hello, this is a really open ended question. Could you either add a lot of information about your actual setup or reduce the scope of your question ? We can't really put a fully fledged addon in an answer here, so you may have to cut your problem into smaller, more achievable chunks. Just a friendly heads-up if you want an actual answer :) cheers

Comment: There's a quick tutorial from Johnny Matthews [here](https://youtu.be/msJSpHTvOuk) which might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you, but he said random order. I can't change it to the correct order on this basis

Comment: Why not? Around 6:00 into the tutorial can't you use the Object Index from the Object Info node instead of the Random Index to calculate which tile to select for your 'page'? I've not tried it, but that's why I said the tutorial could give you an idea of how to do it and you wouldn't need to use python to do it.